# How to handle asynchronous functions in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node to pre-process `.csv` files into `.json` file for that I'm using the `CSVTOJSON` npm package.

I want to wait for the parsing to finish and then start up the uploading procedure to the database.

I found that Node is required to chain functions with callbacks in order to asynchronously execute them.

But I can't figure out how to apply to my program.

**Here is the code**.

```
// 1. Read *.csv file + Parse fields and escape; @dir "raw_data" =>  @dir "processed"
fs.readdir(rawDataPath, function (err, files) {
  if (err) return console.log("Unable to scan raw_data : " + err);

  console.log("Processing csv files to JSON...");
  console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

  files.forEach(function (file) {
    console.log(`CSV ${file.split(".")[0]} being converted...`);

    csv({ ignoreEmpty: true })
      .fromFile("raw_data/" + file)
      .then((jsonObj) => {
        // stringify JSON Object
        var jsonContent = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

        fs.writeFile(
          `processed_data/${file.split(".")[0]}.json`,
          jsonContent,
          "utf8",
          function (err) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(
                "An error occured while writing JSON Object to File."
              );
              return console.log(err);
            }

            console.log(
              `${file} successfully converted to ${file.split(".")[0]}.json`
            );
          }
        );
      });
  });
});

// 2. Upload to Cloud Firestore
fs.readdir(processedDataPath, function (err, files) {
  if (err) return console.log("Unable to scan processed_data : " + err);

  files.forEach(function (file) {
    var quiz = require("./processed_data/" + file);

    console.log(`Collection ${file.split(".")[0]} being updated...`);

    quiz.forEach(function (obj) {
      firestore
        .collection(`${file.split(".")[0].toUpperCase()}`)
        .doc(obj.id)
        .set(obj)
        .then(function (docRef) {
          console.log(
            `Document ${obj.id} successfully uploaded to Cloud Firestore!`
          );
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Look up promises, async await. Is a more manageable way of coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to handle the asynchronous nature of Javascript. I will use `fs.readFile()` as an example to make it easy. These are some of the approaches -

1. **Callbacks** - Passing a function as an argument to be called after an asynchronous task is done.

```
fs.readFile('./some-file.txt', (err, res) => {
  if (err) {                   // err is null if success
    return console.log(err);   // handle error
  }
  console.log(res);            // handle success
});
```

2. **Promises** - This is a globally available object in Javascript to handle asynchronous tasks in a deferred manner. It also gives the capability of chaining multiple promises.

```
fs.promises.readFile('./some-file.txt').then((res) => {
  console.log(res);            // handle success
}).catch((err) => {            // only gets executed if there is an error
  console.log(err);            // handle error
});
```

Chaining -

```
fs.promises.readFile('./some-1.txt').then((res) => {
  return fs.promises.readFile('./some-2.txt');            
  // handle success - 1
}).then((res) => {
  return fs.promises.readFile('./some-3.txt');            
  // handle success - 2
}).then((res) => {            
  // handle success - 3
}).catch((err) => { 
  console.log(err);
  // handle error            
});
```

3. **Async/Await** - This is an easier way to handle promises and was introduced in ES2017. Also, note that Async/Await will only work with promise returning functions.

```
const main = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fs.promises.readFile('./some-file.txt');
    console.log(res)
    // handle success
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    // handle error
  }
}
```

Further reading -

- Callbacks - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function
- Promises - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- Async/Await - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate you so much for your kind reply!